# Threadding: Update UI without blocking the thread?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have written a server program that does a lot of jobs in threads simultaneously.

In those threads, I have to update a ListView with status information, but as it is right now using invoke, the thread waits for the UI to finish updating the ListView.

Any good advice to how I can send the status to the ListView and continue the thread while ListView finish updating?

Here's my code...

```
Public Delegate Sub InfoDelegate(status As String)

Public Sub Info(status As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New InfoDelegate(AddressOf Info)
        Me.Invoke(d, status)
    Else
        Dim item As New ListViewItem With {
            .Text = status}

        With lv
            .BeginUpdate()
            .Items.Insert(0, item)
            If .Items.Count > 500 Then
                For i As Integer = Me.lv.Items.Count - 1 To 500 Step -1
                    Me.lv.Items.RemoveAt(i)
                Next
            End If
            .EndUpdate()
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `BeginInvoke` instead.

Comment: Remember that you must call `EndInvoke` too!

Comment: @VisualVincent are you sure? Microsoft doesn't call EndInvoke ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a06c0dc2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes: _"No matter which technique you use, **always** call EndInvoke to complete your asynchronous call."_ - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And I am also certain because I know that from experience. -- What you can do to avoid blocking your thread is calling `EndInvoke` in a method executed on the UI thread.

Comment: Won't calling the EndInvoke make my thread wait for the UI to finish? If so,  it is not better calling BeginInvoke rather than Invoke in my case.

Comment: That depends on _**when**_ you call `EndInvoke`. What .NET Framework version are you targeting? If .NET 4.0 and up you can use a Lambda expression in `BeginInvoke` and pass the `IAsyncResult` to it. Then in the end of that Lambda method you call `EndInvoke` with the `IAsyncResult`. Doing it this way will cause no blocking at all since the async operation is completed by that time.

Comment: I'm on 4.6.2 - do you have an example of this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [**`Control.BeginInvoke()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a06c0dc2(v=vs.110).aspx) to invoke the method asynchronously. However that call needs to be followed by a [**`EndInvoke()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.endinvoke(v=vs.110).aspx) call, or else you will get memory and/or thread leaks.

In the .NET Framework versions 4.0 and up you can utilize [**lambda expressions**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) to pass the `IAsyncResult` returned from the `BeginInvoke` call to the lambda expression itself. Thus, you can call `EndInvoke` without having it block since by the time that it is called the asynchronous operation is already finished.

Here's an example:

```
Dim iar As IAsyncResult = _
    Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                   Info("Status here") 'Calling your Info() method.
                                   Me.EndInvoke(iar)
                               End Sub)
```

Comment: @MojoDK : No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: I believe that you're wrong about having to call `EndInvoke`.  This is from MSDN: "You can call EndInvoke to retrieve the return value from the delegate, if neccesary, but this is not required. EndInvoke will block until the return value can be retrieved".  So, you CAN call `EndInvoke` to get the return value from an invoked function but you don't HAVE to otherwise.

Comment: @jmcilhinney : Then what about: _"No matter which technique you use, always call EndInvoke to complete your asynchronous call"_? It's from the MSDN too: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @jmcilhinney : And from my experience you need to call `EndInvoke`. I've experienced problems such as the UI freezing when too many `BeginInvoke` calls were called without being followed by `EndInvoke`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Is correct and I agree. Personally I have never seen any issues not calling `EndInvoke`. Specifically if using a delegate it's blocked anyways and won't return to the caller until it's finished. Calling `EndInvoke` at this point doesn't matter. In the example you provided It doesn't matter either because when that method is called, it's immediately blocked until it's done and then comes back to the caller, calling `EndInvoke` is irrelevant at this point....

Comment: @VisualVincent, the quote you posted is referring to the `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke` methods of a delegate itself, not the `Control.BeginInvoke` and `Control.EndInvoke` methods.

Comment: @Zaggler : `In the example you provided It doesn't matter either because when that method is called, it's immediately blocked until it's done` - But it shouldn't block since the async operation should already have completed at that time.

Comment: @jmcilhinney : That's true, I didn't take notice of that. Though I'm going to examine the Reference Source because I am curious to which it really is - `EndInvoke` or not?

Comment: Of course, I can't say for sure that `Control.BeginInvoke` and `Control.EndInvoke` don't themselves call the `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke` methods of the delegate that you pass to `Control.BeginInvoke` in the first place.